# Efficient parallel file transfer between two hosts using mutliple 10GbE NIC ports

Tags: networking, centos, vlan, nic, file-transfer

I need to regularly transfer large amounts (several TBs) of video files between two servers on a 10G network. I want to decrease the overall time it takes to finish the job.

I am running CentOS7. I have two servers (A and B) each having a 10GbE card with two ports, and I have a 10GbE switch.

I have assigned IP addresses as follows:

- Host A/port 1: 172.x.1.1
- Host B/port 1: 172.x.1.2
- Host A/port 2: 172.x.2.1
- Host B/port 2: 172.x.2.2

I have created 2 VLANs (100 and 200) on the switch:

- 100: (172.x.1.1, 172.x.1.2)
- 200: (172.x.2.1, 172.x.2.2)

I want to run parallel file transfers between A and B using both ports of both the 10GbE cards simultaneously.

I have managed to make this work, however, I have another host on VLAN 100 (172.x.1.3), which now cannot be accessed from either A or B

Is there any extra configuration I need to do on the servers or the switch to make this kind of setup work?

Note: I have very fast RAID on both servers (so disk IO shouldn't be the bottleneck)

Note 2: I already tried bonding/teaming the NICs. This method doesn't work for me. All modes except balance-rr just send all packets down one connection. And I don't know if my switch will support balance-rr. Tried but no luck

Comment: what is your purpose ? increase transfer speed or bandwidth test ?

Comment: i need to regularly transfer large amounts (several TBs) of video files between the servers. I want to decrease the overall time it takes to finish the job.

Comment: team the nics, Aggregate the ports and voila you csn use 20 gbits, however you may also use 8n case the manual way by select tge iface and tge other ip

Comment: Edited question to answer this

Comment: Can you post more details of your network adapter configuration? Default route, subnet, also details for the third server.

Comment: @swami, if i were you, as 'djdomi' has mentioned i would go for teaming interfaces, then there is a package in Linux which is called axel, getting used for multiple simultaneous downloads.